# Move files from several folders to subfolders

Tags: macos, shell

I have many folders with files in them, in each of them I have a subfolder called `wvfm` . What I want to do is move all the files into each of the wvfm folder.

I tried doing the line below but it is not working

```
for i in "./*"; mv $i "./wvfm"; done
```

but that didn't work quite right

Comment: `"./*"` is looking for a file called `*`, you don't want the quotes there. (But around `$i`!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for` loop (`for i in */; do`) to list the files, then move to the folders to list and save all files in to a variable (`F=$(ls)`).

Then move all your files with excluding your folder (`mv ${F/wvfm/} wvfm`), like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
subdirectory="wvfm"
for i in */; do
cd $i
F=$(ls)
mv ${F/$subdirectory/} $subdirectory
cd ../
done
```

Comment: It worked very well, thanks very much! The explanation was also very helpful

Answer (score 0):

`find *  -maxdepth 0 -type d | xargs -n 1 -I {} mv {}/* {}/wvfm`

should do the trick; quick and dirty.  Not a MacOS user, but works in bash.

Explanation:
`find *  -maxdepth 0 -type d` find all directories at depth 0 (ie: do not descend dirs),
pipe to xargs, using options `-n 1`, operate on one value at a time, `-I replace-str`, string replacement (see [man xargs](https://ss64.com/osx/xargs.html)).
action command: `mv {}/* {}/wvfm` substitues to `mv dirA/* dirA/wvfm` for each dir match.
You will get an "error", `mv: cannot move /wvfm' to a subdirectory of itself, 'wvfm/wvfm'`, but you can ignore / take advantage of it (quick and dirty).

You could cover all bases with:

```
for entry in $(find * -maxdepth 0 -type d); do
   (cd $entry; [[ -d wvfm ]] && \
    find * -maxdepth 0 ! -name wvfm -exec mv {} wvfm \;
   )
done
```

`find * -maxdepth 0 -type d`, again, find only the top-level directories,
in a subshell, change to the input directory, if there's a directory `wvfm`,
look for all contents except the `wvfm` directory and `-exec` the `mv` command
exiting the subshell leaves you back in the starting (root) directory, ready for next input.

Comment: Thanks, it worked very well. I like the explanation as well, its was very helpful. Since the other guy answered first gave the answer to him but thanks!

Comment: I am sorry, I tried but I do not have the reputation for it